# getting error when editing the user details 

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-membership

I am trying to edit and update a selected users details, following the tutorial https://web.archive.org/web/20210306174425/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/052307-1.aspx

I get the following errors in the Error List in VS 2010:

> Error 6   'Comment' is not a member of
>   'System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal'.   C:\projects\FPOS_v2\FamilyAdmin\edit_user.aspx.vb   21  9   C:\projects\FPOS_v2\
>
> Error 5   'Email' is not a member of
>   'System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal'.   C:\projects\FPOS_v2\FamilyAdmin\edit_user.aspx.vb   20  9   C:\projects\FPOS_v2\
>
> Error 2   'FamilyAdmin_edit_user.Private
>   Sub DeleteUser(sender As Object, e As
>   System.EventArgs)' is not accessible
>   in this context because it is
>   'Private'.    C:\projects\FPOS_v2\FamilyAdmin\edit_user.aspx  140
>
> Error 1   'FamilyAdmin_edit_user.Private
>   Sub UnlockUser(sender As Object, e As
>   System.EventArgs)' is not accessible
>   in this context because it is
>   'Private'.    C:\projects\FPOS_v2\FamilyAdmin\edit_user.aspx  138
>
> Error 7   'IsApproved' is not a member
>   of
>   'System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal'.   C:\projects\FPOS_v2\FamilyAdmin\edit_user.aspx.vb   22  9   C:\projects\FPOS_v2\
>
> Error 8   'UnlockUser' is not a member
>   of
>   'System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal'.   C:\projects\FPOS_v2\FamilyAdmin\edit_user.aspx.vb   88  9   C:\projects\FPOS_v2\
>
> Error 4   Property 'User' is
>   'ReadOnly'.   C:\projects\FPOS_v2\FamilyAdmin\edit_user.aspx.vb   11  9   C:\projects\FPOS_v2\

The code for the edit_user.aspx is:

```
<table class="webparts">
<tr>
    <th>User Information</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="details" valign="top">

<h3>Roles:</h3>
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="UserRoles" runat="server" />

<h3>Main Info:</h3>
<asp:DetailsView AutoGenerateRows="False" DataSourceID="MemberData"
  ID="UserInfo" runat="server" OnItemUpdating="UserInfo_ItemUpdating"
  >

<Fields>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="UserName" HeaderText="User Name" ReadOnly="True" HeaderStyle-CssClass="detailheader" ItemStyle-CssClass="detailitem">
    </asp:BoundField>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Email" HeaderText="Email" HeaderStyle-CssClass="detailheader" ItemStyle-CssClass="detailitem"></asp:BoundField>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Comment" HeaderText="Comment" HeaderStyle-CssClass="detailheader" ItemStyle-CssClass="detailitem"></asp:BoundField>
    <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="IsApproved" HeaderText="Active User" HeaderStyle-CssClass="detailheader" ItemStyle-CssClass="detailitem" />
    <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="IsLockedOut" HeaderText="Is Locked Out" ReadOnly="true" HeaderStyle-CssClass="detailheader" ItemStyle-CssClass="detailitem" />

    <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="IsOnline" HeaderText="Is Online" ReadOnly="True" HeaderStyle-CssClass="detailheader" ItemStyle-CssClass="detailitem" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="CreationDate" HeaderText="CreationDate" ReadOnly="True"
     HeaderStyle-CssClass="detailheader" ItemStyle-CssClass="detailitem"></asp:BoundField>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="LastActivityDate" HeaderText="LastActivityDate" ReadOnly="True" HeaderStyle-CssClass="detailheader" ItemStyle-CssClass="detailitem">
    </asp:BoundField>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="LastLoginDate" HeaderText="LastLoginDate" ReadOnly="True" HeaderStyle-CssClass="detailheader" ItemStyle-CssClass="detailitem">
    </asp:BoundField>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="LastLockoutDate" HeaderText="LastLockoutDate" ReadOnly="True" HeaderStyle-CssClass="detailheader" ItemStyle-CssClass="detailitem"></asp:BoundField>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="LastPasswordChangedDate" HeaderText="LastPasswordChangedDate"
    ReadOnly="True" HeaderStyle-CssClass="detailheader" ItemStyle-CssClass="detailitem"></asp:BoundField>
    <asp:CommandField ButtonType="button" ShowEditButton="true" EditText="Edit User Info" />
</Fields>
</asp:DetailsView>
<div class="alert" style="padding: 5px;">
<asp:Literal ID="UserUpdateMessage" runat="server">&nbsp;</asp:Literal>
</div>


<div style="text-align: right; width: 100%; margin: 20px 0px;">
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Unlock User" OnClick="UnlockUser" OnClientClick="return confirm('Click OK to unlock this user.')" />
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Delete User" OnClick="DeleteUser" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are Your Sure?')" />
</div>


<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="MemberData" runat="server" DataObjectTypeName="System.Web.Security.MembershipUser" SelectMethod="GetUser" UpdateMethod="UpdateUser" TypeName="System.Web.Security.Membership">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="username" QueryStringField="username" DefaultValue="zora" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource> 
</td>

</tr></table>
```

The code for the edit_user.aspx.vb is which is where I am getting the error:

```
Partial Class FamilyAdmin_edit_user
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Private username As String

    Private Sub Page_Load()
        username = Request.QueryString("username")
        If username Is Nothing OrElse username = "" Then
            Response.Redirect("users.aspx")
        End If
        User = Membership.GetUser(username)

        UserUpdateMessage.Text = ""
    End Sub

    Protected Sub UserInfo_ItemUpdating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DetailsViewUpdateEventArgs)
        'Need to handle the update manually because MembershipUser does not have a
        'parameterless constructor  

        User.Email = DirectCast(e.NewValues(0), String)
        User.Comment = DirectCast(e.NewValues(1), String)
        User.IsApproved = CBool(e.NewValues(2))

        Try
            ' Update user info:
            Membership.UpdateUser(User)

            ' Update user roles:
            UpdateUserRoles()

            UserUpdateMessage.Text = "Update Successful."

            e.Cancel = True
            UserInfo.ChangeMode(DetailsViewMode.[ReadOnly])
        Catch ex As Exception
            UserUpdateMessage.Text = "Update Failed: " + ex.Message

            e.Cancel = True
            UserInfo.ChangeMode(DetailsViewMode.[ReadOnly])
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub Page_PreRender()
        ' Load the User Roles into checkboxes.
        UserRoles.DataSource = Roles.GetAllRoles()
        UserRoles.DataBind()

        ' Disable checkboxes if appropriate:
        If UserInfo.CurrentMode <> DetailsViewMode.Edit Then
            For Each checkbox As ListItem In UserRoles.Items
                checkbox.Enabled = False
            Next
        End If

        ' Bind these checkboxes to the User's own set of roles.
        Dim userRoles__1 As String() = Roles.GetRolesForUser(username)
        For Each role As String In userRoles__1
            Dim checkbox As ListItem = UserRoles.Items.FindByValue(role)
            checkbox.Selected = True
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub UpdateUserRoles()
        For Each rolebox As ListItem In UserRoles.Items
            If rolebox.Selected Then
                If Not Roles.IsUserInRole(username, rolebox.Text) Then
                    Roles.AddUserToRole(username, rolebox.Text)
                End If
            Else
                If Roles.IsUserInRole(username, rolebox.Text) Then
                    Roles.RemoveUserFromRole(username, rolebox.Text)
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub DeleteUser(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        'Membership.DeleteUser(username, false); // DC: My apps will NEVER delete the related data.
        Membership.DeleteUser(username, True)
        ' DC: except during testing, of course!
        Response.Redirect("manage_members.aspx")
    End Sub

    Private Sub UnlockUser(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        ' Dan Clem, added 5/30/2007 post-live upgrade.

        ' Unlock the user.
        User.UnlockUser()

        ' DataBind the GridView to reflect same.
        UserInfo.DataBind()
    End Sub

End Class
```

The problem is with the **User**. But I don't know how to sort this as im new to all this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated..

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you forgot to define MembershipUser i.e.

```
Partial Class FamilyAdmin_edit_user
     Inherits System.Web.UI.Page      
Private username As String      
Dim User As MembershipUser

Private Sub Page_Load()
.....
```

Currently it is considering User as in 'System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal' and not MembershipUser.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. Thank removed the error. However, now when try to update the record, i get the following error:
 Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
 on the following line: 
 Line 22:         user.Email = DirectCast(e.NewValues(0), String)

Comment: That could be because it might not be able to find the user you are trying to update. i.e. User = Membership.GetUser(username) might be returning null. Set breakpoint on that line and check if User is null after the method call.