# DetailView error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, detailsview, directcast

I am trying to update a user information and get the following error:

> Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object. Description: An
>   unhandled exception occurred during
>   the execution of the current web
>   request. Please review the stack trace
>   for more information about the error
>   and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details:
>   System.NullReferenceException: Object
>   reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 20:         'parameterless
>   constructor   Line 21:  Line 22:
>   user.Email =
>   DirectCast(e.NewValues(0), String)
>   Line 23:         user.Comment =
>   DirectCast(e.NewValues(1), String)
>   Line 24:         user.IsApproved =
>   CBool(e.NewValues(2))

The .vb code is:

```
Protected Sub UserInfo_ItemUpdating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DetailsViewUpdateEventArgs)
        'Need to handle the update manually because MembershipUser does not have a
        'parameterless constructor  

        user.Email = DirectCast(e.NewValues(0), String)
        user.Comment = DirectCast(e.NewValues(1), String)
        user.IsApproved = CBool(e.NewValues(2))

        Try
            ' Update user info:
            Membership.UpdateUser(user)

            ' Update user roles:
            UpdateUserRoles()

            UserUpdateMessage.Text = "Update Successful."

            e.Cancel = True
            UserInfo.ChangeMode(DetailsViewMode.[ReadOnly])
        Catch ex As Exception
            UserUpdateMessage.Text = "Update Failed: " + ex.Message

            e.Cancel = True
            UserInfo.ChangeMode(DetailsViewMode.[ReadOnly])
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Below is the .aspx code for the detailView:

```
 Protected Sub UserInfo_ItemUpdating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DetailsViewUpdateEventArgs)
        'Need to handle the update manually because MembershipUser does not have a
        'parameterless constructor  

        user.Email = DirectCast(e.NewValues(0), String)
        user.Comment = DirectCast(e.NewValues(1), String)
        user.IsApproved = CBool(e.NewValues(2))

        Try
            ' Update user info:
            Membership.UpdateUser(user)

            ' Update user roles:
            UpdateUserRoles()

            UserUpdateMessage.Text = "Update Successful."

            e.Cancel = True
            UserInfo.ChangeMode(DetailsViewMode.[ReadOnly])
        Catch ex As Exception
            UserUpdateMessage.Text = "Update Failed: " + ex.Message

            e.Cancel = True
            UserInfo.ChangeMode(DetailsViewMode.[ReadOnly])
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Any idea how i can sort this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first guess, without seeing more code, would be that your `user` variable is null.  Did you set it when you rendered the page?  I assume your code above is a postback and so `user` lost it's value.

Comment: thanks for your reply... For the full code please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5059125/getting-error-when-editing-the-user-details

Comment: What will i need to change? apologies for my lack of programming knowledge.